# PHP Thruway publish variable

Tags: php, websocket, thruway

I have this code. What I`d like to do is to pass a $d variable to publish event, is there a way to do it and how can i publish variable data using Thruway PHP?

```
$d='123';
$connection->on('open', function (\Thruway\ClientSession $session) use ($connection) {
    //publish an event
    $session->publish('com.app.deposit', ['Hello, world from PHP!!!'], ['d'=>$d], ["acknowledge" => true])->then(
        function () use ($connection) {
            $connection->close(); //You must close the connection or this will hang
            echo "Publish Acknowledged!\n";
        },
        function ($error) {
            // publish failed
            echo "Publish Error {$error}\n";
        }
    );
  });

 $connection->open();
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, got it. Just needed to use

`$connection->on('open', function (\Thruway\ClientSession $session) use ($connection,$d) {`